# Proof Verification: For $\alpha : A \rightarrow A$, $\alpha^{2} = \alpha$ if and only if $\alpha(x) = x$ for all $x \in \alpha(A)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Here's my attempt at the proof for the forward implication:

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ For $\alpha : A \rightarrow A$, $\alpha^{2} = \alpha$ if and only if $\alpha(x) = x$ for all $x \in \alpha(A)$.

$\textit{Proof.}$ Let $\alpha$ be a function from $A \rightarrow A$, and let $\alpha^{2} = \alpha$. Also note that we may write $\alpha^{2}$ as $\alpha\alpha$. For all $x\in \alpha(A)$, we claim that $\alpha(x)=x$.

If we take some arbitrary element in $A$, say $a$, then $\alpha\alpha(a)=\alpha(a)$ is equivalent to $\alpha[\alpha(a)]=\alpha(a)$, by definition of function composition. Thus, when $\alpha$ takes values from the image of $\alpha$, it outputs values only in the image of $\alpha$.

Using this fact, and knowing that elements of the image of $\alpha$ may be written as $\alpha(a)=x$, we can substitute $x$ in, which yields $\alpha(x)=x$ for $x=\alpha(a)\in \alpha(A)$ by definition of the image of a function. $\blacksquare$

I am wondering if this proof is valid and concise enough.

Comment: Functions $\alpha$ with this property are called idempotent functions.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that and it didn't say that in my textbook. Thank you.

Comment: As it stands, your statement is fairly tautologous. You are saying $\alpha^2=\alpha\iff\alpha^2=\alpha$, unless I'm very mistaken

Comment: @FShrike Oh, could you explain further? In my proof, I'm only going in the forward implication direction, so I am assuming that $\alpha^{2}=\alpha$ from the beginning.

Comment: $\alpha(x)=x,\,\forall x\in\alpha(A)$ means: $\alpha(\alpha(y))=\alpha(y),\,\forall y\in A$, which means: $\alpha^2(y)=\alpha(y)$. So by my reading of your question, you are seeking to prove $\alpha^2=\alpha\iff\alpha^2=\alpha$.

Comment: I did not really do any proving there, just expanded out some definitions; the question is peculiar as it stands - where did you find it?

Comment: I see what you mean, the question itself is asking to prove something so trivial. I got it from "Introduction to Abstract Algebra" by Nicholson, 4th edition, section 0.3 Mappings.

Comment: A brief comment,  it seems to be common practice (My Thesis advisor did this) to use multiple versions of the same letter for different related things.  This may help be suggestive to some people,  but there are others who have difficulties making out subtle differences in scripts.  (Hint: Me :))

Comment: @Alan Yep, I can see how my proof would be an eyesore... So many a's! But would you say the proof is fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, here is the proposition to prove.

For any $ \alpha : A \rightarrow A $,

$$(\forall x\in A)\;\;\;\alpha(\alpha(x))=\alpha(x) \iff$$

$$(\forall y\in \alpha(A))\;\;\; \alpha(y)=y$$

Proof of the left to right implication

Let $ y\in \alpha(A)$.

$$y\in \alpha(A) \implies $$
$$(\exists x\in A)\;\;:\; y=\alpha(x)\implies$$

$$ \alpha(y)=\alpha(\alpha(x))=\alpha(x)=y$$

Proof of the converse.

Let $ x\in A$.

$$x\in A \implies \alpha(x)\in \alpha(A)$$

$$\implies \alpha(\alpha(x))=\alpha(x)$$

Done.